# Machine with multiple networks/gateways. SSH through different network from global default GW

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

I have a wired connection with IP/subnet/default gw.  I also have a wireless connection with IP/subnet/default gw.  The default gw of the machine (route -n) is the wired default gw.  But I can only SSH to certain hosts through the wireless network.

If I delete the wired gw, add the wireless gw, and then SSH, I'm able to connect.

$ route del default gw wired_gw_ip

$ route add default gw wireless_gw_ip

$ ssh host

But then all machine traffic runs through wireless_gw_ip.  I'd like to be able to keep most of the machine traffic running through wired_gw_ip, but create some SSH sessions through wireless_gw_ip...  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just have to create routes based on the destination.  So if you want some traffic to a specific destination host/network exit through a particular gateway, then create a route for that.

So something like `ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via wired_gw_ip` would send everything destined for the `10.0.0.0/8` network to the wired gateway.

It is also possible to setup policy based routing, to do things that are a lot more complex.   See the [Advanced Routing HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/)